# Set default value of boolean to false instead of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a type

```
export type ItemResponse = {

....

addedManually: boolean;

....
}
```

At some point I parse a JSON response into this type like this:

```
  const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.com`
    );
    const json: ItemResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(json?.manuallyAdded)
    return json;
```

The console log gives me `undefined`, because my API does not return any value for `manuallyAdded`. This field is only needed for usage inside the client-Application. I expected `manuallyAdded` to be `false` by default, but it is `undefined`. How can I get around this. I would like to avoid manually setting this filed to `false` for each response. Would there be any easy JS/TS way to change the default value without adding another `wrapper-type`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use `!!json?.manuallyAdded`.  I don't think that it gets much easier if you cannot control what your API is returning.

Comment: You can't set a default value in interface or type alias
If you really want it to be a boolean you have no choice but set it to false if undefined

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this:

```
  const json: ItemResponse = {manuallyAdded:false,...await response.json()};
```

if manuallyAdded comes from server it will be overrided

Answer (score 0):

`response.json()` will only deserialize fields that actually exist in the response. If `manuallyAdded` doesn't exist, it will be undefined. If you want it to be false you have to set it to false yourself. One way is like this:

```js
const defaultItemResponse: ItemResponse = { 
    manuallyAdded: false,
    // other default values if you need them
};

const json: ItemResponse = await response.json();
const item = { ...defaultItemResponse, ...json };
console.log(item?.manuallyAdded)
return item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, technically you can't set a default value for interface fields, it doesn't mean it's a hopeless situation. Let's consider a simple use-case:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    x?: boolean,
    y: string
}

const defValue = {
    x: false,
    y: "some default value"
}

const test = {
    y:"hello"
}

console.log({
    ...defValue,
    ...test
})
```

This is just a dirty approach. If you use TS, you can benefit from types like Pick, Omit, Partial to make your code cleaner, I would also recommend to create a factory method like:

```
const create = (val: SomeInterface): SomeInterface => ({...defValue, ...val})
```

which you can use on demand wherever you need to fill in default values.
If you used classes instead of interfaces, that'd make things a bit easier as you could set those up in a constructor, and actually ensure the fields.